# InexactError: Int64 even when checking divisibility

Tags: julia

Im having problems with dividing large numbers. I have a while loop that divides the number if the index is within the array limits and if its remainder is zero:

```
        while ((i + j*arr[i]) <= lim && arr[i + j*arr[i]] % arr[i] == 0)
            arr[i + j*arr[i]] /= arr[i]
        end
```

Im using an array of Int64 on max value of `arr[i]<(150*10^6)^2`, even changing to Int128 doesnt help,
BigInt is out of the question because it takes too much time.
I dont understand why I get Inexact error inside the loop if it enters only if the remainder is zero.
and `typemax(Int64)>max(arr)`
here is the full error:

```
InexactError: Int64(1.8014400929875968e15)
in top-level scope at P-146-Investigating a Prime Pattern:51
in test at P-146-Investigating a Prime Pattern:39
in setindex! at base\array.jl:826 
in convert at base\number.jl:7 
in Int64 at base\float.jl:710
```

it seems to happen only after the value in the array is above `(90*10^6)^2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TLDR: use `÷`.

Dividing integers with the `/` function in Julia returns floating point numbers.  Importantly, it *promotes* integers to floating point numbers *before* it does the division.  For example, the number `10^16-1` is obviously divisible by three:

```
julia> 9999999999999999 % 3
0
```

However, if we try to do this division with `/`, we don't get the correct answer:

```
julia> 9999999999999999 / 3
3.3333333333333335e15

julia> using Printf

julia> @printf "%f" 9999999999999999 / 3
3333333333333333.500000
```

So of course, trying to store the above number in an integer array is going to throw an inexact error.  But why is this?  Well you're above `maxintfloat(Float64)`.  Since floating point numbers have ~15 decimal digits of precision, above this value they are no longer able to exactly represent every single integer.  They start skipping (and rounding!) them.  Thus you're not really dividing `10^16-1` by three, you're dividing 10^16 by three!

```
julia> 10^16-1
9999999999999999

julia> Float64(10^16-1)
1.0e16
```

Much better to use `÷` (that is, `div`) — not only will it handle these cases without worrying about floating point precision, but it'll also keep things as integers:

```
julia> 9999999999999999 ÷ 3
3333333333333333
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that `/` operation produces `float`, so following `=` tries to assign float value to an element of the array which is of the `Int` type. Consider this example

```
> a = [11]
> b = [2]
> a[1] /= b[1]
ERROR: InexactError: Int64(5.5)
Stacktrace:
 [1] Int64 at ./float.jl:710 [inlined]
 [2] convert at ./number.jl:7 [inlined]
 [3] setindex!(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Float64, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:849
 [4] top-level scope at REPL[6]:1
```

So it tries to assign `5.5` to the element of the array which consists of `Int`.

You can do one of the following, depending on your task

1. One way or another declare arrays as arrays of float

```
> a = [11.0]
1-element Array{Float64,1}:
 11.0
> b = [2.0]
> a[1] /= b[1]
5.5
```

2. Use integer division (`div` or equivalently `÷`) to make a division

```
> a = [11]
> b = [2]
> a[1] ÷= b[1]
5
```

As for your original question, why it produces this error, I think that since you have rather big numbers, after converting to float and the following division you get an inexact result, which cannot be converted back to `Int`.

Comment: But I do a remainder check, I don't divide 11 by 2 because the remainder is 1,I divide only when it's zero hence the error confuses me. Your answer also doesn't mention why with lower values it doesn't happen but after some threshold it does. Though thanks for taking the time for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

Using the integer division `÷`/`div`i s sometimes kind of risky - you might loose value due to rounding and not even notice. Hence, in many cases consider using Julia's support for rational numbers.

```
julia> u = 9999999999999999 // 3
3333333333333333//1

julia> u % 3 == 0
true
```

Because of the way rational numbers are stored you can expect good performance (although not as good as in integer division):

```
julia> dump(u)
Rational{Int64}
  num: Int64 3333333333333333
  den: Int64 1
```

Comment: Note that the OP is explicitly looking for and ensuring even divisibility, so this really isn't a concern in this case.